# PayPal IPN Error and custom port IPN URL

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal, paypal-ipn

My IPN URL is http://:85/ it has a custom port. This url is working fine but paypal is always giving me errors on its simulator and not calling my IPN on payments.

What would be causing this problem?

Comment: the IPN URL Is: http://someip:someport/somepath

Comment: post some code what you have tried? Did u enable IPN in paypal settings.

Comment: I m using sandbox mode. Do i still need to enable IPN Settings from there?

Comment: Enable IPN in Profile .. Click on More Function and search for Instant Payment Notification. Check it.. Let me know if any issues

Comment: I m using sandbox developer accounts and in profile I didn't see any option for enabling IPN. I have options there for my email address, password and my name only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the steps to enable IPN in paypal Sandbox

1. Log in to the Sandbox Merchant Id and click the Profile subtab under My Account.
2. Click the More Option link under Profile.
3. Look Selling Preferences which is third row.
4. Click the Instant Payment Notification Preferences link under Selling Preferences
5. Enter the IPN URL

Update the Settings....

Comment: thanx. With this I also needed to change my listening port from 85 to 80.

Answer (score 9):

The IPN listener needs to listen on the standard port for http(80) resp. https(443) otherwise it doesn't work... This is not specified in the documentation and it doesn't make sense so it is quite confusing!

Comment: Thanks so much, same problem