# Paypal IPN sandbox returning 502 bad gateway error in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, nginx, paypal-ipn

I'm implementing Paypal IPN in NodeJS with express but I am getting this error message from Paypal Sandbox:

```
<html> <head><title>502 Bad Gateway</title></head> <body bgcolor="white"> <center><h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1></center> <hr><center>nginx/1.6.0</center> </body> </html>
```

I used the paypal-ipn dependency and below is my code:

```
.post('/paypal_ipn', function(req, res) {
    var params = req.body;
    var ip = req.ip;
    console.log(params);

    res.status(200);
    ipn.verify(params, {'allow_sandbox': true}, function callback(err, mes) {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
        } else {
            // Do stuff with original params here
            if (params.payment_status === 'Completed') {
              // Payment has been confirmed as completed
            }
        }
    });
```

})

I tried configuring http and https on port 3000 but got the same error message.

Any ideas on this?

Comment: I would like to add that I tested using .get instead of .post and I can see that the console.log was firing. But I needed the POST since this is how Paypal IPN sends notification.

Comment: Just ran into the same problem and the solution for me was the answer from here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11609174/paypal-ipn-error-and-custom-port-ipn-url/17359452#17359452