# Paypal sandbox IPN simulator - 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I've just finish implementing a Payment Gateway Server that supports Paypal. The gateway also has an adaptive IPN server for Paypal and Skrill notifications. During implementation and tests, I used the documentation provided by Paypal's [IPN manual](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/). During tests, everything went "All Okay". I test it with the example given by the documentation, "All Okay":

```
mc_gross=19.95&protection_eligibility=Eligible&address_status=confirmed&payer_id=LPLWNMTBWMFAY&tax=0.00&address_street=1+Main+St&payment_date=20%3A12%3A59+Jan+13%2C+2009+PST&payment_status=Completed&charset=windows-1252&address_zip=95131&first_name=Test&mc_fee=0.88&address_country_code=US&address_name=Test+User&notify_version=2.6&custom=&payer_status=verified&address_country=United+States&address_city=San+Jose&quantity=1&verify_sign=AtkOfCXbDm2hu0ZELryHFjY-Vb7PAUvS6nMXgysbElEn9v-1XcmSoGtf&payer_email=gpmac_1231902590_per%40paypal.com&txn_id=61E67681CH3238416&payment_type=instant&last_name=User&address_state=CA&receiver_email=gpmac_1231902686_biz%40paypal.com&payment_fee=0.88&receiver_id=S8XGHLYDW9T3S&txn_type=express_checkout&item_name=&mc_currency=USD&item_number=&residence_country=US&test_ipn=1&handling_amount=0.00&transaction_subject=&payment_gross=19.95&shipping=0.00
```

The problem started when we deployed the gateway to our production server, and went testing with the simulation form provided by Paypal's [IPN Simulator](https://developer.paypal.com/developer/ipnSimulator). Well, when I clicked the `Send IPN` button, the message didn't reached my server, and after a few seconds (*more like minutes*), an HTTP error status response appeared:
[image]

Yes **502 Bad Gateway**! What the heck is that?!? The message did not even got to server. A few remarks, we are not using the standard 80/443 ports, and we only support "POST" messages. Again the IPN message is not getting into our server, we test it with other testing tools, and the message arrives successfully.

> **Please help!**

**>> We are using Express Checkout by the way!**

Comment: Have you solved this issue? I am getting the same error message.

Comment: Just ran into the same problem and the solution for me was the answer from here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11609174/paypal-ipn-error-and-custom-port-ipn-url/17359452#17359452

Answer (score -1):

You should avoid putting the host in your headers.
**Change this:**

```
    $header  = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    $header .= "Host: www.paypal.com\r\n"; *****DELETE THIS LINE*****
    $header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";
```

**For this:**

```
    $header  = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";
```

Comment: Hey nmos, thank you for your response, but I think you didn't got the question. The IPN Simulator is actually the requestor for our IPN listener. These are our response for every server request: `Content-Length: 4 
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1 
Connection: keep-alive
Date: Sun, 14 Jun 2015 22:46:51 GMT 
Server: SIGMA-IPN-Server/1.0`