# PayPal IPN listener URL: What are valid ports?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I came accross a question with an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17359452/1972266) which solved my issue with PayPal's IPN listener's URL, saying that the URL has to be using port 80(http) or 443(https). This was for Sandbox's IPN Simulator.

Is this true also for live IPN listener? Or you can have a URL with another port.

Comment: I guess everything is allowed... They will send you a "ping" message in order to save the URL and use it... so you will immediately know if your URL works or not.